# Tkinter. StringVar(). How I can update the Label in my code.

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I have a problem with updating the Label widget (lab1_datum_in).
I would like to change the Label text every time I change radiobuttons.
Really do not know what is wrong.
Could anyone help?
My interpreter is Python 3.4

Thanks in advance!

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()

# Creating radiobuttons
v = tkinter.IntVar()
v.set(1)  # initializing the choice

transformation_types = [
    ("WGS84  -->  ED50(North of 62N)",1),
    ("WGS84  -->  ED50(South of 62N)",2),
    ("ED50(North of 62N)  -->  WGS84",3),
    ("ED50(South of 62N)  -->  WGS84",4),
    ]

datum_in_text = tkinter.StringVar()
datum_in_text.set('WGS84')


def ChangeDatumText():
    if v.get() == 1:
        global datum_in_text
        datum_in_text.set('WGS84')

    elif v.get() == 2:
        global datum_in_text
        datum_in_text.set('WGS84')

    elif v.get() == 3:
        global datum_in_text
        datum_in_text.set('ED50(North of 62N')

    elif v.get() == 4:
        global datum_in_text
        datum_in_text.set('ED50(North of 62N')


for txt, val in transformation_types:
    tkinter.Radiobutton(root,
                        text=txt,
                        padx=20,
                        variable=v,
                        command=ChangeDatumText,
                        value=val).grid()

lab1_datum_in = tkinter.Label(root, text=datum_in_text.get()).grid(row=9, column=1)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: That should be `textvariable=datum_in_text`, not `text=datum_in_text.get()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jonrsharpe indicated in a comment, to slave the text displayed on the Label widget you need to set the `textvariable` option to a control variable of class `StringVar`, which in your case is `datum_in_text`. The `text` option you have is for displaying a one or more lines of static text.

This means you need to use:

```
lab1_datum_in = tkinter.Label(
                    root, textvariable=datum_in_text).grid(row=9, column=1)
```

instead of what you have.

BTW, all those `global datum_in_text` declarations you have in the `ChangeDatumText()` function are unnecessary and all but the first produce non-fatal syntax warnings when they're encountered. Since you're only calling one of the global variable's methods, rather than assigning a value to the variable name itself, you don't even need do this, but if you do put one in—it doesn't hurt—just declare it global once at the very beginning of the function.

*Another thing* to be aware of is that the variable `lab1_datum_in` will be set ti `None` by the assignment because the `grid()` method doesn't return anything — so you should split it up into two separate steps.

Comment: Thank you. I was too stubborn and was focused too much on the other thing in the 'code'.